# Turn off power saving options via command line

Tags: windows-vista, energysmart, power-saving

On Windows XP, the following command in a script will prevent any power saving options from being enabled on the PC (monitor sleep, HD sleep, etc.).  This is useful for kiosk applications.

```
powercfg.exe /setactive presentation
```

What is the equivalent on Vista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

powercfg.exe works a little differently in Vista, and the "presentation" profile isn't included by default (at least on my machine.  so you can setup a "presentation" profile and then use the following to get the GUID

> ```
> powercfg.exe -list
> ```

and the following to set it to that GUID:

> ```
> powercfg.exe -setactive GUID
> ```

Alternatively, you can use powercfg.exe with the -change or -X to change specific parameters on the current power scheme.

Snippet from "powercfg.exe /?":

> -CHANGE, -X Modifies a setting value in the current power scheme.
>
> ```
>           Usage: POWERCFG -X <SETTING> <VALUE>
>
>           <SETTING>   Specifies one of the following options:
>                       -monitor-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                       -monitor-timeout-dc <minutes>
>                       -disk-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                       -disk-timeout-dc <minutes>
>                       -standby-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                       -standby-timeout-dc <minutes>
>                       -hibernate-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                       -hibernate-timeout-dc <minutes>
>
>           Example:
>               POWERCFG -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 5
>
>           This would set the monitor idle timeout value to 5 minutes
>           when on AC power.
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Setting a value to never can be done by passing a value of `0` to the `-change` option, i.e.:

```
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
```

means the monitor timeout will be set to "Never".  So the presentation plan can be achieved via:

```
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -disk-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
```

Answer (score 4):

(at least) for windows 7:

Nice Shortcuts are:

- powercfg -ALIASES # Lists named aliases for available profiles.
- powercfg -S SCHEME_MIN #Activates the (High-Performance) Scheme with the alias SCHEME_MIN
- powercfg -S SCHEME_MAX #Activates the (Max-Energie-Saving) Scheme with the alias SCHEME_MAX
- powercfg -S SCHEME_BALANCED # ... Balanced Energie Scheme

cheers

Kai

Answer (score 1):

C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /list

### Existing Power Schemes (* Active)

Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *

Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)

Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)

C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /setactive a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a

Answer (score 0):

In Vista you create a power profile and use the commandline powercfg to select that profile  [see here](http://www.nooblet.org/blog/tag/powercfg/)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg -change -disk-timeout-ac 0
powercfg -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
```

This will work